# i got some error xpression #9 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column

Tags: php, web

Expression #9 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'nilai.b.id_nilai' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

```
$x['sudah']=$this->db->query("select * from siswa a, nilai b where a.id_siswa=b.id_siswa group by b.id_siswa");
```

Comment: Dude, first you have to learn SQL, this is completely messed up ... Then ask a better, more detailed question, containing more examples, etc.

Comment: Is that the actually error message, or did you add more information to it? Tag the type of DB being used, not `website`.